# Non-resizable frame in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to create a non-resizable frame to give a message:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define (non_resizable_frame)
  (define myframe (new frame% 
                         [label "MyFrame"]
                         [style (list 'no-resize-border)] ; does not work.
                         ))
  (new message% [parent myframe][label "This is just for testing."])
  (new message% [parent myframe][label "I am trying to create a non-resizable frame."])
  (send myframe show #t))

(non_resizable_frame)
```

However, the frame still is resizable. Where is the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: I am still able to resize the frame by placing the mouse at right lower corner and dragging the corner. I want frame to be of a fixed size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `stretchable-width` and `stretchable-height` init arguments to `#f` when constructing the frame.

Comment: Yes, it works. What is 'no-resizable-border for? It does not seem to do anything.